# AWS EC2 Dotnet netcoreapp3.1 working on my phone but not on my pc

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am an absolute AWS novice. I am following a step by step deployment guide provided by a bootcamp I am attending. I have a simple dotnet mvc app built that has been thoroughly tested, and I've got it cloned on my web server. I am able to run it with no errors, but when I visit my AWS url the connection times out, and this is what most people experience. However, on my phone and my mother's computer it works fine, as in the project is clearly present and interactable. I am baffled by this. I have retraced my steps, repeating the process from the beginning 4 times over now with the same problem reoccurring. None of my classmates are having this issue.

https://ec2-52-53-152-128.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Perhaps this link will work for you, perhaps not.

I am using nginx to listen on port 80 and reroute from port 5000 (my previous local host port). I simply have the project running using dotnet run before moving on to the next stage. Below is a picture of my security settings on my ec2 instance:

[security settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LCnE.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am happy to provide any additional information that would be useful.

Comment: "AWS url the connection times out" - this is because your link is `https` (port 443), but application is `http` (80). Thus, you have to access it using `http` only. Once you do this you will see nginx error message indicatign that you nginx is set incorrectly or you application crashed.

Comment: You're a legend, thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcin who replied to my question. The links generated by AWS are https, and my application goes through http. Hence when dropping the s from the url, it fixes it.